# Symfony 4: Keep SQLite PDO connection in test + controller + twig extensions

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, pdo, twig

### My situation

I have a Symfony 4.2 project with the following structure:

- src

  - Controller
  - Service
  - Twig Extensions
- Templates
- Tests

I use a database class, which internally creates a PDO connection. If i run my tests with PHPUnit, my database class has to switch from mysql to sqlite. Everything works fine here.

### My problem

I can not keep the once created Database instance, when running just **one** test. Symfony seems to recreate it during the test: when inside a Twig template which uses a Twig extension. Because the database class uses

```
new \PDO('sqlite::memory:');
```

it loses created tables and therefore the test fails. I am aware of, that the Database instance (with PDO reference) gets reseted after each test, but in my situation i only have one test. **How can i ensure, that it re-uses the Database instance?**

#### Here the related code

InstanceExtension class provides the function title, which is used in a Twig template and has to access the database.

```
<?php

namespace App\TwigExtension;

use App\Service\Database;
use Twig\TwigFunction;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;

class InstanceExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    protected $db;

    /**
     * @param Database $db
     */
    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    /**
     * Tries to return the title/name for a given ID.
     *
     * @param string $subject
     * @param string|array $tables
     * @param string $lang         Default is 'de'
     *
     * @return string label or id, if no title/name was found
     */
    public function title(string $subject, $tables, string $lang = 'de'): string
    {    
        return $this->db->get_instance_title($subject, $tables, $lang);
    }
}
```

In my **services.yaml** the `Database` class is set to public (which should enable reusing it, doesn't it?):

```
App\Service\Database:
    public: true
```

#### Database class

Here is the part of the Database class which initializes the PDO connection. Production code, which uses MySQL instead, removed:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Service;

class Database
{
    /**
     * @param Config $app_config
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function __construct(Config $app_config)
    {
        global $sqlite_pdo;

        try {
            // non test
            // ..

            // test environment
            } else {
                $this->db_engine = 'sqlite';

                // workaround to ensure we have the same PDO instance everytime we use the Database instance
                // if we dont use it, in Twig extensions a new Database instance is created with a new SQLite
                // database, which is empty.
                if (null == $sqlite_pdo) {
                    $pdo = new \PDO('sqlite::memory:');
                    $sqlite_pdo = $pdo;
                } else {
                    $pdo = $sqlite_pdo;
                }
            }

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            if (\strpos((string) $e->getMessage(), 'could not find driver') !== false) {
                throw new \Exception(
                    'Could not create a PDO connection. Is the driver installed/enabled?'
                );
            }

            if (\strpos((string) $e->getMessage(), 'unknown database') !== false) {
                throw new \Exception(
                    'Could not create a PDO connection. Check that your database exists.'
                );
            }

            // Don't leak credentials directly if we can.
            throw new \Exception(
                'Could not create a PDO connection. Please check your username and password.'
            );
        }

        if ('mysql' == $this->db_engine) {
            // ...
        }

        // default fetch mode is associative
        $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // everything odd will be handled as exception
        $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $this->db = $pdo;
    }

    // ...
}
```

One test looks kinda like:

```
<?php 

class SalesChannelControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        // init Database class, using SQLite
        $this->init_db();

        // further setup function calls

        // SalesChannelController is a child of
        // Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController
        $this->fixture = new SalesChannelController(
            $this->db
            // ...
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns a ready-to-use instance of the database. Default adapter is SQLite.
     *
     * @return Database
     */
    protected function init_db(): Database
    {
        // config parameter just contains DB credentials
        $this->db = new Database($this->config);
    }

    public function test_introduction_action()
    {
         // preparations

         /*
          * run action
          *
          * which renders a Twig template, creates a Response and returns it.
          */
         $response = $this->fixture->introduction_action($this->request, $this->session, 'sales_channel1');

         /*
          * check response
          */
         $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    } 
}
```

**My current workaround is to store the PDO instance in a global variable and re-use it, if required.**

```
<?php 

global $sqlite_pdo;

// ...

// inside Database class, when initializing the PDO connection
if (null == $sqlite_pdo) {
    $pdo = new \PDO('sqlite::memory:');
    $sqlite_pdo = $pdo;
} else {
    $pdo = $sqlite_pdo;
}
```

If you need more info, please tell me. Thanks for your time and help in advance!

Comment: Could you post how your test looks like? This seems to be intended behavior as the in memory-context should be cleared between each test leaving you with an empty database. To be sure and to suggest a good approach it would help to see the test setup you are using.

Comment: Hi @dbrumann, i will update my initial question.

Comment: *Because i couldn't update my previous comment:* I updated the question and clarified the problem. Also provided the requested test case. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It could already help to store the fixture inside a static variable and then use `public static function setupBeforeClass()` instead of just setup. This will keep the fixture between each test. Let me know if it helps or if you need a full example. It might still depend on what `init_db` does. It would help to see the content of that function as well.

Comment: Hi @dbrumann, setupBeforeClass would be possible. But i was wondering, if i can configure it in Symfony itself. Any idea?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is nothing related to your Symfony application, e.g. booting a kernel and getting the connection from the container, in your test. If you want a test database that can be used throughout the test suite, what I usually do is create a bootstrap script that creates an sqlite-file in my `var/` folder, use the Doctrine commands to build the schema and then point the `DATABASE_URL` used by Symfony to that file. For an example see this demo project: https://github.com/dbrumann/todo-basic/blob/master/tests/bootstrap.php

Comment: As i wrote in my initial question, it resets the PDO connection while rendering a Twig template. This is done in a Controller action. Symfony is involved most of the time. Parts, not related to Symfony, working just fine. Because Database is a Service, i was wondering, how to configure it to be reused without re-instantiation.

Comment: If that database stuff were a service, it is reused without reinstantiation. Why don't you use that service within the test case?

Comment: I thought i did. Please see in my question the `InstanceExtension`, which has `Database` as first parameter. That is the class, which handles the PDO stuff. InstanceExtension provides the `title` function, which i use in a twig template. This template is rendered in my test case via a Controller action, called `introduction_action` (from Controller `SalesChannelController`, a child from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController`). **But the Database instance gets re-instantiated by Symfony, for some reason i dont know.**

Comment: Setting the service to `public` should not make a change here, but what does `init_db` do?

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase, I will update my initial question and add these information.

Comment: Well, now we are getting there: why do you create a new instance of that database class on every setup? Why don't you use your container for that?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am not sure, if i understand you correctly. What do you mean by "use your container"? Is there a best practice here, which i can follow?

Comment: Of course there is: when you use a container (like you do, as you use Symfony services), you should not instantiate the services by hand, but fetch them from the container